Overpass Turbo: Get single railway line between two cities
Edit: Sorry for the unclear question, here is a new attempt:
Is there a code library to get the gps coordinates along certain tracks? E.g., to get the railway line between Leipzig and Dresden?

Could you be m ore specific?  Like "Is there a code library that will help generate a line between 2 GPS points?"  or "Is there software that can show the shortest route between to GPS points?  - QGIS plugin"

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I suspect there's not direct line, since all trains should go through Leipzig. Furthermore, there are most likely two tracks, hence you can't get a single railway line. Sounds like you're trying to get overpass to do routing for you.

Overpass is not the right tool for routing, GraphHopper could be an option: https://www.geofabrik.de/projects/railway_routing/index.html
